# How do I get the name of the pipeline from inside the jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**env.JOB_NAME** Is the pipeline name suffixed with the branch name.

So **env.JOB_NAME** will be `<jenkins_pipeline_name>_<my_branch>`

How can I just get the pipeline name and store it in a var in the environment{} block at the top of my jenkinsfile to use through the file?

I don't want to resort to scripted pipeline just the declarative.

Comment: `env.JOB_NAME` only returns my pipeline job name. It shouldn't be returning the name with a branch name suffix.

Comment: even for a multi branch pipeline? because this is what I am seeing

Answer (score 38, accepted):

@red888 pointed out the following answer that worked like magic for me. I am pointing it out in an actual answer because I almost missed it:

`env.JOB_BASE_NAME`

Credit to @red888 in the comment above. Send upvotes his/her way.

Comment: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746902/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-pipeline-from-inside-the-jenkinsfile#comment78527249_45763385) by [red888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028270/red888)

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using the multibranch job, the env variable is returning the actual job name that it created out of the branch .i.e. _ ..  So, without some mechanism to strip/sed out the branch name, i don't think there is an env variable for it in jenkins out-of-the-box.

Comment: How can I parse this in a declarative pipeline? I want to have this variable defined in my environment{} block at the top of my jenkinsfile so I can use it throughout the file. But I can't do groovy functions in the environment{} block. How do I do this in a declarative (NOT scripted) pipeline?

Comment: env.JOB_BASE_NAME is the answer

Comment: In a multibranch pipeline, env.JOB_BASE_NAME is only the branch name -- see [JENKINS-44278](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44278).

Answer (score 7):

You can check `http://YOUR-JENKINS-SERVER.com/pipeline-syntax/globals#env` and it'll get you

```
JOB_NAME
  Name of the project of this build, such as "foo" or "foo/bar".
JOB_BASE_NAME
  Short Name of the project of this build stripping off folder paths, such as "foo" for "bar/foo".
```

For a jenkins organization project with multiple branches and PRs, the `JOB_NAME` is actually `YOUR_ORG_NAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME/YOUR_BRANCH_OR_PR_NAME`, e.g. `my-org/my-repo/PR-23`, and the `JOB_BASE_NAME` is just `PR-23`. Just as [Israel said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58758308/3134333), you can use `env.JOB_NAME.tokenize('/') as String[]` to get what you want.

If you want more fancy scripts in Jenkins, [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/index.html) can be a good reference.

Answer (score 5):

In jenkins pipeline

```
def allJob = env.JOB_NAME.tokenize('/') as String[];
def projectName = allJob[0];
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`env.JOB_NAME` is the project name... There is no DOUBT

However, my issue with copyArtifact plugin. It said :

```
Unable to find project for artifact copy: YOUR_PROJECT_WITH_ARTIFACTS
This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings;
```

At the end it is not "incorrect project name", and `env.JOB_NAME` must work.
However, the issue is permission settings which can be fixed generally by :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    copyArtifactPermission('*');
  }
  //..
}
```

[Reference](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/#copyartifactplugin-permissionstocopyartifact)